# Transforming implicit 2D region into explicit integral bounds

Tags: integration, multiple-integral, implicit-function

If I have a 2D region defined as follows:

\begin{align}
&(1) \qquad u^2-v^2 \leq a \\ 
&(2) \qquad u^2-v^2 \geq -a \\ 
&(3) \qquad u \geq 0 \\ 
&(4) \qquad v \geq 0
\end{align}

and I want to take a double integral over this region, are my bounds correct?

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{a}} dv \int_0^{\sqrt{v^2+a}} du ~ F(u,v)+\int_{\sqrt{a}}^\infty dv \int_{\sqrt{v^2-a}}^{\sqrt{v^2+a}} du ~ F(u,v)$$

If not, what's my mistake?

I need this to solve a PDE in parabolic coordinates.

Comment: It's correct. The region is bounded by the coordinate axes and two hyperbolas. The vertex of the second hyperbola is at $(v, u) = (\sqrt a, 0)$, so the $u$ range is from zero to the first hyperbola when $v < \sqrt a$ and between the two hyperbolas when $v > \sqrt a$.

Comment: The way I understand, these are two hyperbola - Hyperbola A: one along $u$ axis, $(u^2 - v^2) \le a$; the other Hyperbola B: along $v$ axis, $(v^2 - u^2) \le a$. As $u, v \ge 0$, we have to only consider first quadrant. Are you trying to take combined region in the first quadrant between i) the u-axis and Hyperbola A branch and ii) v-axis and the hyperbola B branch? OR are you taking the first quadrant region between the branches of hyperbola A and hyperbola B?

Comment: If it is the latter then it is definitely correct.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers!